# Virtual Keyboard recommendations (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, keyboard, virtual

Im looking for recommendations for JavaScript virtual keyboards (that aren't built with jQuery). So far I have only been able to find ones made with jQuery but I don't want to add jQuery to my project when everything else is written with native JS.

Anyone know of a native framework agnostic virtual keyboard solution?

I would usually never use such a thing as the device keyboard should be preferred in my opinion but in this project we can use that, our devices are 48" android where the keyboard is 48" wide - very unusable, and the project is not native android based so we can use a native keyboard replacement.

If anyone has any tip let me know.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use the keyboard from the link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13748/JavaScript-Virtual-Keyboard).This is a way to generate key board . Hope this helps , You can add comment if you want any further help .